# How to plot element count and add annotations

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I was working "globalterrorism.csv" and wanted to visualise terrorist attacks in each country. I did this for the same:

```
len(gt['country_txt'].unique())
```

And I got 205 unique countries.

```
labels = gt.groupby(["country_txt"]).count()['eventid'].index


x = np.array(list(gt.groupby(["country_txt"]).count()['eventid']))
```

while x is :

```py
x = np.array([12629, 80, 2690, 1, 492, 1, 776, 23, 113, 112, 48, 5, 207, 1636, 3, 13, 151, 5, 8, 6, 309, 159, 10, 253, 6, 51, 52, 610, 248, 330, 94, 283, 87, 2352, 248, 7922, 5, 67, 57, 30, 130, 32, 10, 759, 41, 22, 3, 87, 38, 10, 210, 2479, 5274, 2, 9, 16, 167, 1, 17, 20, 2678, 7, 3, 8, 3, 206, 728, 19, 1268, 5, 56, 1984, 23, 8, 26, 212, 317, 26, 46, 4, 11748, 752, 1, 677, 24553, 299, 2171, 1536, 72, 35, 399, 107, 26, 677, 194, 73, 32, 27, 17, 2417, 28, 28, 2249, 8, 16, 33, 116, 25, 5, 95, 21, 561, 23, 12, 17, 2, 497, 21, 5, 36, 355, 543, 150, 1194, 121, 30, 1, 19, 1949, 148, 3864, 1, 6, 19, 14261, 126, 86, 113, 3, 6050, 6761, 39, 140, 7, 36, 83, 6, 2143, 157, 371, 117, 12, 11, 2, 87, 7, 18, 6, 4, 4093, 2015, 38, 225, 1, 2, 75, 3208, 2998, 2, 1, 942, 65, 16, 131, 107, 2198, 49, 181, 58, 3836, 48, 22, 107, 4260, 2, 390, 1708, 21, 5222, 2824, 76, 20, 2, 1, 273, 12, 1, 2196, 537, 4, 3309, 200, 50, 62, 100])
```

-len is 205

```
ax = plt.figure(figsize = (12,7))
plt.hist(x, bins = 205)
```

This is the result:

[image]

But I need to plot all the values of 'x' and have the lables against each of them!!

Can somebody tell me how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Using the data from [data.world: Global Terrorism Data](https://data.world/data-society/global-terrorism-data). Select a file to download, and then choose the option to **Download all files**. Extract the files into the default folder name.

  - The total data set is `157520 rows × 137 columns`
- Plot the data with `kind` as `'bar'` or `'barh'`, not `'hist'`
- Instead of `.groupby`, using `.value_counts` will simplify the code.
- Annotate with `ax.bar_label`. See [Adding value labels on a matplotlib bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982/7758804) for more annotation information

  - Use older annotation methods shown in [Adding value labels on a matplotlib bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28931224/7758804) if upgrading `matplotlib` isn’t an option.
- Using `pandas v1.2.4` and `matplotlib v3.4.2`.

```py
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

# find the files
files = Path('data-society-global-terrorism-data/').glob('*.csv')

# create a single dataframe of the 4 csv files
gt = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file, low_memory=False) for file in files]).reset_index(drop=True)

# display(gt.loc[:5, ['country_txt', 'eventid']]
        country_txt       eventid
0  Northern Ireland  199301010001
1             Egypt  199301010002
2         Sri Lanka  199301030001
3            Israel  199301030002
4            Israel  199301030003
5  Northern Ireland  199301030004

# groupby and get the top 20
# gtg = gt.groupby(["country_txt"])['eventid'].count().sort_values(ascending=False).head(20)

# optional: using value_counts is easier
gtg = gt.country_txt.value_counts().head(20)

# plot the figure as a bar plot, not a histogram
ax = gtg.plot(kind='barh', figsize=(7, 12))

# annotate the bars
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[-1], label_type='edge')

# bump out the x margin so the annotation doesn't stick out
ax.margins(x=0.1)
```

[image]

### Two Columns of Sample Data

```py
data = {'country_txt': ['Colombia', 'Afghanistan', 'Colombia', 'Colombia', 'Pakistan', 'India', 'India', 'Colombia', 'India', 'Colombia', 'Colombia', 'Colombia', 'Colombia', 'Colombia', 'Colombia', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'Pakistan', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'Colombia', 'Colombia', 'Colombia', 'Afghanistan', 'India', 'Pakistan', 'Colombia', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Colombia', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'Colombia', 'Colombia', 'India', 'Pakistan', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'Pakistan', 'Colombia', 'Colombia', 'Colombia', 'India', 'India', 'Colombia', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'India', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'India', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'India', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'India', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'India', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'India', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'India', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'India', 'Pakistan', 'India', 'India', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'India', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'India', 'India', 'Pakistan', 'India', 'India', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'India', 'India', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'India', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'India', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'India', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Colombia', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'India', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Colombia', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'India', 'India', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Colombia', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'Colombia', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'India', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Colombia', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'India', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'India', 'Iraq', 'India', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Colombia', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Colombia', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'India', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'India', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'India', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'India', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'India', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'India', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'India', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'India', 'India', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'India', 'India', 'Afghanistan', 'India', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'India', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'India', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'India', 'India', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Colombia', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'India', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Colombia', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'Colombia', 'Colombia', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Colombia', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'India', 'India', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'India', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'India', 'India', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'India', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'India', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'India', 'India', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'India', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'India', 'Colombia', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'India', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'India', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'India', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'India', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'India', 'Afghanistan', 'Colombia', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'India', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'India', 'India', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'India', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'India', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'India', 'Afghanistan', 'India', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'India', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'India', 'India', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Colombia', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'India', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'India', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'India', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'India', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'India', 'Pakistan', 'India', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Colombia', 'Pakistan', 'India', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'India', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Afghanistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq', 'Iraq'], 'eventid': [199301080003, 199301170001, 199301170007, 199301210001, 199301220001, 199301220005, 199301260001, 199301300002, 199301300003, 199301310002, 199302010001, 199302150001, 199302150002, 199302230001, 199302250001, 199303120002, 199303120003, 199303120004, 199303120005, 199303120006, 199303120007, 199303120008, 199303120009, 199303120010, 199303120011, 199303120012, 199303120013, 199303120014, 199303120015, 199303120016, 199303120018, 199303140002, 199303160006, 199303170004, 199303270002, 199303280002, 199303310001, 199304060002, 199304150001, 199304160002, 199304230002, 199304240004, 199305010002, 199305290003, 199306010001, 199306060002, 199306130001, 199308030001, 199308030002, 199308030003, 199308040001, 199308080003, 199308140010, 199308250002, 199309020002, 199309020003, 199309030003, 199309060002, 199309130009, 199309170001, 199309170002, 199309250003, 199309290002, 199310070001, 199310070002, 199310070003, 199310180001, 199310290002, 199311050001, 199311080001, 199311290002, 199312060002, 199312060003, 199312060004, 199312060005, 199312120003, 199312130003, 201201010001, 201201010003, 201201010005, 201201010006, 201201010007, 201201010008, 201201010009, 201201010012, 201201010014, 201201010015, 201201010016, 201201010017, 201201010018, 201201020002, 201201020003, 201201020005, 201201020006, 201201020007, 201201020008, 201201020009, 201201020010, 201201020012, 201201020016, 201201020017, 201201020018, 201201020019, 201201020020, 201201020023, 201201020024, 201201020025, 201201020026, 201201030002, 201201030004, 201201030008, 201201030009, 201201030010, 201201030011, 201201030012, 201201030013, 201201030014, 201201030015, 201201030016, 201201030017, 201201030018, 201201030023, 201201030026, 201201030028, 201201030029, 201201030036, 201201030037, 201201030038, 201201030046, 201201030048, 201201040002, 201201040005, 201201040009, 201201040011, 201201040012, 201201040013, 201201040014, 201201040015, 201201040016, 201201040017, 201201040018, 201201040021, 201201040023, 201201040024, 201201040025, 201201040026, 201201040027, 201201040031, 201201040034, 201201050001, 201201050002, 201201050004, 201201050005, 201201050006, 201201050007, 201201050008, 201201050010, 201201050011, 201201050012, 201201050013, 201201050017, 201201050019, 201201050020, 201201050021, 201201050029, 201201060001, 201201060003, 201201060004, 201201060011, 201201060012, 201201060013, 201201060014, 201201060015, 201201060016, 201201060017, 201201060018, 201201060019, 201201060020, 201201060021, 201201060024, 201201060025, 201201060026, 201201060032, 201201060033, 201201060034, 201201060036, 201201060038, 201201070001, 201201070003, 201201070005, 201201070006, 201201070008, 201201070009, 201201070010, 201201070012, 201201070013, 201201070014, 201201070015, 201201070016, 201201070017, 201201070019, 201201070021, 201201070023, 201201070024, 201201080001, 201201080002, 201201080003, 201201080004, 201201080005, 201201080006, 201201080008, 201201080012, 201201080013, 201201080014, 201201080015, 201201080016, 201201080020, 201201080021, 201201080022, 201201080023, 201201080024, 201201080026, 201201080027, 201201080028, 201201090002, 201201090003, 201201090007, 201201090008, 201201090009, 201201090010, 201201090011, 201201090012, 201201090013, 201201090014, 201201090023, 201201090025, 201201090027, 201201100002, 201201100007, 201201100008, 201201100009, 201201100010, 201201100011, 201201100015, 201201100016, 201201100021, 201201100022, 201201100025, 201201100026, 201201100027, 201201100032, 201201100033, 201201100034, 201201100036, 201201100037, 201201100038, 201201100039, 201201100040, 201201100041, 201201110001, 201201110002, 201201110004, 201201110005, 201201110006, 201201110008, 201201110009, 201201110010, 201201110013, 201201110017, 201201110019, 201201110024, 201201110025, 201201110027, 201201110035, 201201110036, 201201110037, 201201120001, 201201120002, 201201120003, 201201120004, 201201120005, 201201120007, 201201120008, 201201120009, 201201120010, 201201120011, 201201120012, 201201120015, 201201120016, 201201120017, 201201120018, 201201120022, 201201120023, 201201120024, 201201130001, 201201130002, 201201130003, 201201130004, 201201130005, 201201130006, 201201130007, 201201130010, 201201130013, 201201130015, 201201130016, 201201130017, 201201130018, 201201130019, 201201140001, 201201140005, 201201140007, 201201140010, 201201140011, 201201140013, 201201140014, 201201140018, 201201140019, 201201140021, 201201150001, 201201150002, 201201150003, 201201150004, 201201150005, 201201150006, 201201150011, 201201150012, 201201150016, 201201150017, 201201150018, 201201150021, 201201150022, 201201150024, 201201160001, 201201160002, 201201160006, 201201160007, 201201160012, 201201160013, 201201160014, 201201160015, 201201160016, 201201160022, 201201160024, 201201160026, 201201160027, 201201160031, 201201160036, 201201170002, 201201170003, 201201170004, 201201170006, 201201170007, 201201170013, 201201170015, 201201170016, 201201170017, 201201170022, 201201170023, 201201170024, 201201180001, 201201180003, 201201180004, 201201180005, 201201180009, 201201180012, 201201180013, 201201180014, 201201180016, 201201180023, 201201180026, 201201180027, 201201180028, 201201180029, 201201190001, 201201190002, 201201190003, 201201190006, 201201190007, 201201190013, 201201190015, 201201190017, 201201190018, 201201190019, 201201190020, 201201190021, 201201190022, 201201190023, 201201190027, 201201200010, 201201200011, 201201200013, 201201200014, 201201200015, 201201200019, 201201200021, 201201200022, 201201200032, 201201200033, 201201210003, 201201210004, 201201210007, 201201210009, 201201210010, 201201210011, 201201210012, 201201210013, 201201210014, 201201210015, 201201210016, 201201210020, 201201210021, 201201210022, 201201210023, 201201210024, 201201210028, 201201210029, 201201210030, 201201210031, 201201210032, 201201210033, 201201210037, 201201210038, 201201220002, 201201220003, 201201220004, 201201220009, 201201220010, 201201220018, 201201230002, 201201230003, 201201230008, 201201230010, 201201230015, 201201230016, 201201230017, 201201230018, 201201230019, 201201230021, 201201230022, 201201230023, 201201230024, 201201230025, 201201240002, 201201240003, 201201240004, 201201240005, 201201240006, 201201240007, 201201240008, 201201240009, 201201240011, 201201240014, 201201240017, 201201240018, 201201240019, 201201240021, 201201240025, 201201240026, 201201240027, 201201240029, 201201240030, 201201250001, 201201250002, 201201250003, 201201250004, 201201250005, 201201250006, 201201250007, 201201250009, 201201250011, 201201250012, 201201250013, 201201250014, 201201260001, 201201260003, 201201260005, 201201260006, 201201260008, 201201260009, 201201260010, 201201260011, 201201260014, 201201260018, 201201260019, 201201260022, 201201260024, 201201260025, 201201260030, 201201260031, 201201260033, 201201260036, 201201260037, 201201270001, 201201270002, 201201270006, 201201270008, 201201270009, 201201270010, 201201270012, 201201270015, 201201270017, 201201270021, 201201270022, 201201280003, 201201280005, 201201280007, 201201280009, 201201280010, 201201280011, 201201280012, 201201280013, 201201280015, 201201280017, 201201280020, 201201280021, 201201280022, 201201280025, 201201280026, 201201280027, 201201280029, 201201290002, 201201290004, 201201290006, 201201290008, 201201290009, 201201290010, 201201290012, 201201290014, 201201290015, 201201290020, 201201300003, 201201300004, 201201300005, 201201300006, 201201300013, 201201300014, 201201300015, 201201300016, 201201300019, 201201300021, 201201300026, 201201310001, 201201310006, 201201310008, 201201310009, 201201310010, 201201310012, 201201310013, 201201310014, 201201310015, 201201310016, 201201310017, 201201310018, 201201310019, 201201310020, 201201310023, 201201310024, 201202010001, 201202010002, 201202010003, 201202010006, 201202010007, 201202010008, 201202010011, 201202010014, 201202010015, 201202010016, 201202010020, 201202010023, 201202010024, 201202020001, 201202020002, 201202020003, 201202020004, 201202020005, 201202020007, 201202020009, 201202020010, 201202020011, 201202020013, 201202020014, 201202020016, 201202020017, 201202020018, 201202020024, 201202020025, 201202030002, 201202030004, 201202030006, 201202030007, 201202030011, 201202030013, 201202030015, 201202030016, 201202030019, 201202030020, 201202040001, 201202040002, 201202040003, 201202040004, 201202040005, 201202040006, 201202040007, 201202040008, 201202040009, 201202040013, 201202040014, 201202040015, 201202040016, 201202040020, 201202050002, 201202050003, 201202050004, 201202050005, 201202050006, 201202050015, 201202050018, 201202050019, 201202050020, 201202060003, 201202060004, 201202060005, 201202060006, 201202060014, 201202060015, 201202070001, 201202070006, 201202070007, 201202070008, 201202070009, 201202070010, 201202070011, 201202070012, 201202070013, 201202070014, 201202070015, 201202070019, 201202070020, 201202070021, 201202070026, 201202080002, 201202080003, 201202080004, 201202080005, 201202080006, 201202080007, 201202080008, 201202080009, 201202080010, 201202080011, 201202080012, 201202080013, 201202080018, 201202090002, 201202090008, 201202090009, 201202090011, 201202090022, 201202090023, 201202090024, 201202100001, 201202100002, 201202100005, 201202100006, 201202100008, 201202100009, 201202100010, 201202100011, 201202100012, 201202100013, 201202100019, 201202100020, 201202100023, 201202100024, 201202110001, 201202110002, 201202110003, 201202110004, 201202110005, 201202110019, 201202110020, 201202110021, 201202110022, 201202110028, 201202110029, 201202110030, 201202110031, 201202120001, 201202120002, 201202120003, 201202120004, 201202120005, 201202120006, 201202120009, 201202120010, 201202120012, 201202120013, 201202120014, 201202120015, 201202130001, 201202130002, 201202130003, 201202130004, 201202130005, 201202130006, 201202130007, 201202130009, 201202130019, 201202140001, 201202140002, 201202140003, 201202140004, 201202140007, 201202140016, 201202140019, 201202140021, 201202150001, 201202150002, 201202150003, 201202150004, 201202150005, 201202150006, 201202150017, 201202150018, 201202160001, 201202160002, 201202160003, 201202160004, 201202160005, 201202160006, 201202160010, 201202160013, 201202160016, 201202160018, 201202170001, 201202170002, 201202170003, 201202170004, 201202170008, 201202170012, 201202170015, 201202170016, 201202170025, 201202180001, 201202180002, 201202180024, 201202190001, 201202190004, 201202190005, 201202190006, 201202190007, 201202190009, 201202190010, 201202190011, 201202190012, 201202190017, 201202190022, 201202190026, 201202190027, 201202190028, 201202200001, 201202200002, 201202200003, 201202200004, 201202200005, 201202200012, 201202200013, 201202200014, 201202200018, 201202210001, 201202210002, 201202210003, 201202210004, 201202210007, 201202210008, 201202210009, 201202210011, 201202210021, 201202210022, 201202210023, 201202210028, 201202210031, 201202210033, 201202220002, 201202220008, 201202230001, 201202230002, 201202230003, 201202230004, 201202230005, 201202230006, 201202230007, 201202230008, 201202230009, 201202230010, 201202230011, 201202230012, 201202230013, 201202230014, 201202230015, 201202230016, 201202230017, 201202230018, 201202230019, 201202230021, 201202230022, 201202230023, 201202230024, 201202230025, 201202230027, 201202230028, 201202230029, 201202230030, 201202230038, 201202230040, 201202230045, 201202230046, 201202230047, 201202230049, 201202230050, 201202230051, 201202230052, 201202230053, 201202230054, 201202240001, 201202240004, 201202240005, 201202240006, 201202240011, 201202240012, 201202240013, 201202240014, 201202240016, 201202240018, 201202240019, 201202250001, 201202250003, 201202250004, 201202250006, 201202250008, 201202250009, 201202250011, 201202250012, 201202250013, 201202250014, 201202250015, 201202250016, 201202250017, 201202250018, 201202250019, 201202250020, 201202250021, 201202250022, 201202250025, 201202260001, 201202260002, 201202260003, 201202260004, 201202260007, 201202260008, 201202260009, 201202260010, 201202260015, 201202260016, 201202260017, 201202260021, 201202260022, 201202260023, 201202260024, 201202260025, 201202260026, 201202260027, 201202260028, 201202260029, 201202270001, 201202270004, 201202270011, 201202270022, 201202270023, 201202270024, 201202270025, 201202270027, 201202270028, 201202270029, 201202280001, 201202280002, 201202280003, 201202280004, 201202280005, 201202280006, 201202280013, 201202280014, 201202280015, 201202280022, 201202280024, 201202280025, 201202280026, 201202280027, 201202280029, 201202280031, 201202280033, 201202290001, 201202290002, 201202290003, 201202290004, 201202290005, 201202290006, 201202290008, 201202290012, 201202290015, 201202290017, 201202290020, 201202290026, 201202290028, 201202290029, 201202290030, 201203010001, 201203010003, 201203010004, 201203010005, 201203010006, 201203010007, 201203010021, 201203010022, 201203010028, 201203010029, 201203010030, 201203020002, 201203020003, 201203020004, 201203020005, 201203020006, 201203020007, 201203020008, 201203020012, 201203020013, 201203020020, 201203020022, 201203030003, 201203030004, 201203030005, 201203030006, 201203030007, 201203030008, 201203030012, 201203030013, 201203030014, 201203030015, 201203030016, 201203030017, 201203030019, 201203030023, 201203030025, 201203030030, 201203040001, 201203040002, 201203040003, 201203040004, 201203040005, 201203040006, 201203040011, 201203040012, 201203040014, 201203040015, 201203040018, 201203040019, 201203040021, 201203050001, 201203050002, 201203050003, 201203050004, 201203050005, 201203050006, 201203050007, 201203050011, 201203050012, 201203050014, 201203050015, 201203050016, 201203050019, 201203060002, 201203060013, 201203060014, 201203060015, 201203060016, 201203060017, 201203060018, 201203060019, 201203060026, 201203060028, 201203060029, 201203060030, 201203060032, 201203070001, 201203070002, 201203070003, 201203070004, 201203070005, 201203070006, 201203070007]}
gt = pd.DataFrame(data)
```